# "Change the Look" try it out not loading

Tags: theme

I have tried everything to change the theme on my sharepoint site, every time I change something and click the "Try it Out" button, it gets stuck and won't leave that "Working on it" page...

Comment: Do you have this with specific browser?

Comment: Whether its online or on-premises? Which version?

Comment: I've been experiencing this issue on Office365 with multiple browsers (IE11, Chrome, and Edge 15).  Possible explanation/workaround: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/issues/1622  Technet discussion on the matter: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-Groups/Unable-to-Change-the-look-and-feel-for-Office-365-groups-site/td-p/52272